# WSO2 - Error on validating payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am facing an alarming situation with the services published in WSO2 ESB. In an absolutely random way, some services fail the response message validation, in spite of the fact that de response is totally correct. The error deals with missed tagges in the payload. This takes place with no pattern at all. A services is working until it starts to respond a validation fault. When this occurs, I check the following:

- A soapUI client can be generated by the WSDL published by the ESB, so it is not a reference issue.
- Response is validated successfully by the XSD used by the validate mediator. (validated by an alternative tool).

I can even see the payload that previously is logged and it is correct. This have occured several times in different services.

The only way to fix this is undeploy the services and deploy it again. I have try the redeploy option in the service dashboard, and reset the whole system with no success.

I have a feeling that somehow the payload used by the validate mediator is a kind of locked, blank, unreachable or dirty.

How can I set the validate mediator process in debug mode? I think this might help.

Any help? I am thinking of denying using this system in a production environment.

I use wso2 esb 4.5.1.

King regards.

Answer (score 0):

Put the log mediator with the log level ="full" before the validate mediator and see, what is passed to the validate mediator. This will help you to find the erroneous response..